# Activating a piston in real life with a plugin in Minecraft

Tags: javascript, c#, html, plugins, minecraft

It's going to sound a little strange. Basically what I currently have is a javascript/spigot plugin that detects when a player takes damage. I need help with two things: causing that even to get sent to an external source (I was thinking a website hosted on my computer, especially since the server I'll use the plugin on will also be hosted on my computer). After sending out that signal, I need the website to pick up the signal and send it to a piston (in real life, not a Minecraft piston). I essentially need the piston to push out whenever it detects health being lost, and then quickly pull back in. Essentially I'm going to hook it up to an airsoft gun for a very traumatizing video I want to record for Youtube xD. Any recommendations for how I might go about doing that? I only have a little experience with javascript, CSharp, and HTML. It's also been a few years so I've lost most of it (Don't use it, you lose it). I haven't ordered a piston yet, so if anyone has a recommendation, that would be helpful as well.

Comment: Its been a long time since I did any Minecraft modding, but you're probably taking about the Java version. Minecraft modding is relatively simple, Java is also very similar to c#. I would suggest you [make a mod](https://codakid.com/guide-to-minecraft-modding-with-java/) that sends a post to a [server on the local machine](https://dzone.com/articles/simple-http-server-in-java) when the player health changes. That server would then control the piston. There is probably a fair amount of effort involved in this project if you're not particularly familiar with programming.

Answer (score 0):

First you don't activate the piston an electric airsoft gun works with motor that turns a gear witch pulls the piston out on a spring and after enough energy stored spring force pushes the piston back very fast into the chamber creating high pressure pushing the BB out.
I found this video that can give you an image about what is going on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2jySLznBnk
What you need to do after you send that signal find a way to activate the motor.You pretty much replace the trigger with some kind of relay, or something else.The most easy option is to use something like raspberry pi that can fetch the information from server and activate the relay that activates a gun.